# Corresponding these set of numbers to dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a set of numbers that correspond to the following dates in javascript.

```
1499040000 -> 07/03/17
1498780800 -> 06/30/17
1498694400 -> 06/29/17
1498608000 -> 06/28/17
```

I am trying to figure out what kind of javascript function can correspond the number to the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number is an [Unix Epoch Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Thursday, 1 January 1970,[2] Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), minus leap seconds.

To convert it, you can use the first and accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Comment: Hi, if you think it is duplicate, please vote to close.

Comment: Actually not duplicate, since op doesn't know what is an Unix timestamp.

Comment: Did you actually vote to reopen?

Comment: Yes @adiga, I think that the questions you marked as duplicated doesn't explain what is an Unix timestamp, only how to convert it to a date, so it's an incomplete answer and different question.